# UDP sendto() fails after calling I/O or sleep()

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I came across a very weird bug. I have a struct `sender` which encapsulates resources needed by a UDP sendto(). The sender has a `send()` method which encapsulates BSD socket `sendto()`.

The following code works.

```
  alice = sender(bob_ip, bob_port);
  alice.send();
```

**BUG** the following code fails

```
  alice = sender(bob_ip, bob_port);
  puts("====");
  alice.send();
```

It is **so weird** that, if I put I/O or sleep operations (e.g. the puts("====") here) inside the `alice.send()` method. It still works.

Can anybody explains why does this happens? 
Complete Source code:

```
// To run this code: ./sender <remote-ip> <remote-port>
#define IP4_STR_LEN 20
unsigned bob_port;
char bob_ip[IP4_STR_LEN];

int msg_len;
char msg[50];

const size_t SOCKADDR_IN_LEN = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);


typedef struct sender {
  int sockfd_s;
  struct sockaddr* rem_addr;
} sender;

static void init(sender* this, char* rem_ip, int rem_port) {
    this->sockfd_s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in local_in, rem_in;
    memset(&rem_in, 0, sizeof(rem_in));
    rem_in.sin_family = AF_INET;
    rem_in.sin_port = htons(rem_port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, rem_ip, &(rem_in.sin_addr));
    this->rem_addr = (struct sockaddr*)&rem_in;
}

static int sendudp(sender* this){
        int msg_snt_len = sendto(this->sockfd_s, msg, msg_len, 0, this->rem_addr, SOCKADDR_IN_LEN);
        printf("msg_snt_len: %d\n", msg_snt_len);
        return msg_snt_len;
}

sender alice;

static void test() {
    init(&alice, bob_ip, bob_port);
  puts("====");
    sendudp(&alice);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  strcpy(bob_ip, argv[1]);
  sscanf(argv[2], "%u", &bob_port);

  strcpy(msg, "Hello World!");
  msg_len = strlen(msg);

    test();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this even compile? As C? I **really** don't think so ...

Comment: @unwind no. doesn't matter though. I just used C++ for lazy, sender()=default; and not typing the "struct " prefix.

Comment: Of course it matters, you can't tag a question as 'c', supply some broken C++, and expect help. At least I don't think you can.

Comment: You probably have some code that's causing undefined behavior. This often causes random errors like this.

Comment: @unwind I tag C because most of it is C. and the real question here is socket sendto. However, thank you for bringing up this comment. I will change it to complete C right now. Thx.

Comment: At a minimum, you're assigning pointer values from stack variablee (`rem_addr = (sockaddr *)&rem_in;`), this data will then get clobbered when you call the `puts()`. You need to store the actual sockaddrs, not pointers to the sockaddrs in order for the code to have a chance of working consistently.

Comment: @unwind I update the code to pure C code. At least GCC builds it successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're initializing the structure to point to variables that only exist as locals inside the  `init()` function.

As soon as that function exits, those pointers are invalid and dereferencing them (as `sendto()` does since you pass that pointer to it). will give you undefined behavior.

You should add the actual address data to the structure itself, so it stays around.